# How to display another value if the column is null?

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I am new to Birt reporting.
My requirement is that, I want to display "N/A" when the actual value of the column is null.

For ex: `select vendor from account where id=1;`

o/p: NULL

so, in place of null  values in the report I want to display those fields as N/A. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Value-Mapping in the Data-Cell where you want to display your value by the following:

Click in the Data-Cell where you want to display the value. Go to the "Property Editor" and select the Tab "Map". Click an "Add..." Select your value from the dropdown, select "Equal to" for the comparison, enter "null" for the value to compare to. Enter "N/A" for the alternative Value to display and click OK.

[image: create a value mapping in birt]